# Keeping Cloudformation documents for RDS and app separate, but linked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

Putting my DB definition and my application server definition in the same cloudformation document has pros and cons:

*Pros:*

- DB hostname, username and password can be provided to the app servers without leakage
- Single document to define stack

*Cons:*

- Communicating the DB hostname, username and password to the app servers is a bit messy, and involves Fn::Join and Fn::GetAtt in hard to read user data
- The lifecycle of the database is tied to the lifecycle of the stack

So I am currently going the other way - have a cloudformation document that defines an RDS arrangement, and a separate cloudformation document that defines my app layer.  Also pros and cons:

*Pros:*

- Lifecycle of DB is separated from app stack
- Can have multiple app stacks using the same DB stack

*Cons:*

- DB stack must be manually edited to add the EC2 Security Group, so the app stack can get access to the DB
- No longer a single document defining my stack

Its the first con of the second approach that is bothering me - having to manually edit my DB stack before my app stack will work.  So I cannot bring up a new app stack cleanly without having to get in there at the right time and make the necessary edit.

Is there a way for my app stack to reconfigure the existing DB stack with the necessary DB security group setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an ingress/egress for the security group used by the RDS in question within the app CF template as well as the app security group, despite the resources for the RDS CF stack not having been provisioned by the app CF stack.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html.

You would then have a parameter for the SecurityGroup resource id which you would Ref for the GroupId in the ingress, as well as the egress from app security group (DestinationSecurityGroupId). (Though you could hard code the resource id in there if you so desired.....)
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html.